# Sudden suspicious change of public IP

Tags: networking, router, vpn, ip-address

I have a phone that has suddenly changed public IP. I noticed this when trying to stream location based content.

It only appears to do this on WiFi as I do not see this new IP when connected mobile data only.

Other devices on this WiFi do not experience this change in public IP and see the same IP as the router has when I look their's up.

On the problem phone:

The IP is:
35.214.169.79
and changed once to
35.214.200.218

The reported host name is:
79.163.214.35.bc.googleusercontent.com
and changed once to
218.200.214.35.bc.googleusercontent.com

I've tried googling around with no results, I'm sorry if this is not an appropriate place to ask this question.

I'm pretty worried that the phone's traffic is being routed somewhere else maliciously and have already begun changing passwords and such.

Hope someone can provide an explanation, thank you.

Comment: Posting your IP address online probably isn't the best idea for starters

Comment: Haha thank you for good advice, but the IPs posted are not my routers public IP

Answer (score 0):

Your public IP is given to you automatically by your ISP. These are generally dynamic and it is completely normal for them to change over time.They are only assigned to you for periods of time from a pool of IP addresses owned by your ISP. Static public IPs which do not change are available, but are usually reserved for businesses. There is no reason for panic, this is ordinary behaviour.

Comment: I know the public IP of my router, I got that IP on other devices at the same time this happened

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the phone just has a VPN enabled.

Addresses with rDNS of "bc.googleusercontent.com" belong to servers hosted on Google Compute Engine. It might be some commercial VPN hosted on GCE, or Google's own "Google One" VPN service.

Comment: VPN was my first thought. I went over all installed apps and found nothing.  Would a google app ever create a VPN connection without any notification? Google One was definately not in use.

Comment: Generally not without showing at least the "key" icon in the status bar. (Pixel phones may sometimes establish an automatic VPN when using what they determine to be a [public Wi-Fi network](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6327199?hl=en), but I believe this still shows the "key" icon and a notification.) There is also the "Data saver" aka "Lite mode" feature in Google Chrome, which proxies websites (and only websites) via Google servers.